# Isometric laying cylinder Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

Okay this may be a bit OCD.

How do you make a perfect isometric cylinder like this?

[image: Isometric cylinder]

Connecting the two circles has always been eyeballing for me. How do you make it perfect?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use Illustrator's 3D Extrude & Bevel. Start with a flat circle and go to **Effect → 3D → Extrude & Bevel...**

There are isometric presets already available.

[image]

Another option is to use an isometric grid. There is a nice tutorial on creating an isometric grid in Illustrator here: [How to Create an Isometric Grid in Less than 2 Minutes!](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-an-isometric-grid-in-less-than-2-minutes--vector-3831).

1. Use the **Rectangular Grid Tool** to create a uniform grid.
2. **Object → Transform → Scale**, check Non-Uniform and set Vertical scale to 86,602%
3. **Object → Transform → Shear** at 30 degrees
4. **Object → Transform → Rotate** at -30 degrees
5. **View → Guides → Make Guides**

Answer (score 2):

I draw stuff like that all the time. Usually I use the [Common Tangents](http://shspage.com/aijs/en) script by *Hiroyuki Sato*. It works quite well and helps you in any other find the tangent situation too. I find the script indispensable.

Comment: Very useful scripts!